# Using copy with whitespace in batch file

Tags: file, batch-file, whitespace

I have a script to copy file in batch file:

- `copy C:\File\text.txt C:\FileCopy\text.txt`
  --> It's ok. But when I use
- `copy C:\File\text.txt C:\File Copy\text.txt`
  --> It doesn't work because "File Copy" has whitespace. The system can not find the patch specified.

Answer (score 1):

Use quotation marks:

```
copy "C:\File\text.txt" "C:\File Copy\text.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes

```
copy "C:\File\text.txt" "C:\File Copy\text.txt"
```

[check](http://jpsoft.com/help/copy.htm)